# Populate form from two entities

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to populate form from database by using two entities. Here's the code I use

CategoryType

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

    class CategoryType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('name', 'text');
        }


       public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $options)
        {
            return array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Category',
            );
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'questionnaire';
        }
    }
```

ProductType

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Product',
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'questionnaire';
    }
}
```

CommonType

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use AppBundle\Form\CategoryType;
use AppBundle\Form\ProductType;


class CommonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('category', new CategoryType());
        $builder->add('product', new ProductType());
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_common_type';
    }
}
```

DefaultController

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\CommonType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->findOneBy(['id' => 2]);
        $form = $this->createForm(new CommonType(), $data);

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:index.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);

    }
}
```

But I get this error

```
The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Category. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Category" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Category to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.
```

So what I'm doing wrong and is this the correct way to populate form based on two or more entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Common form's model data format is an array (as far as no data_class given). So the right data to set is an array with `product` and `category` keys:

```
    $product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->findOneBy(['id' => 2]);
    $form = $this->createForm(new CommonType(), ['product' => $product]);
```

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested but now I get this error
 

The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class AppBundle\Entity\Product. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "AppBundle\Entity\Product" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class AppBundle\Entity\Product to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.

Comment: Here's the dump of the data

`DefaultController.php on line 20:
Product {#555 ▼
  #id: 2
  #name: "second"
  #price: "12.00"
  #description: "testing"
  #category: Category {#572 ▼
    +__isInitialized__: false
    -id: 2
    -name: null
    #products: null
     …2
  }
}`

Comment: What version of Symfony do u use? `getDefaultOptions` is deprecated in modern builds, `configureOptions` or at least `setDefaultOptions` preferred.

Comment: yeah, `getDefaultOptions` is useless then.

Comment: I changed with configureOptions but got the same error

Comment: ok, as i supposed it is a bit misused. Write $options->setDefaults(['data_class' => ...]); instead of `return ...`;

Comment: That did the job thanks. Unfortinatelly only the product field is populated. Category is empty. What I'm missing?

Comment: Add category object `$this->createForm(new CommonType(), ['product' => $product, 'category' => $someCategory]);`